# Tor Relay: Alleged Family Members

Tags: relays, atlas, myfamily

First of all sorry for my English.

I had 2 Tor relays and now 1 is gone. I cleared "MyFamily" in torrc, and after some time dead relay disappeared from "Effective Family Members" in Tor Metrics website, but now it's in "Alleged Family Members" and nothing happens to him for a long time. What did i do wrong? How can i clear this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will eventually dissapear on its own. There is nothing you did wrong, and nothing else you can do to remove it on your own.